# How to auto scroll to a specific div in angular8 after clicking on a button to open an ngx-flyout?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

Assuming I have a small div of size 200px width and height with overflow:y using ngx-flyout: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-flyout

I have the following HTML with significant text in the body:

My flyout html is:

```
<ngx-flyout [(open)]="openFlyout">
<div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow-y:true">
<div id="A">Lorem ipsum..... </div>
<div id="B">Lorem ipsum..... </div>
<div id="C">Lorem ipsum..... </div>
<div id="D">Lorem ipsum..... </div>
<div id="E">Lorem ipsum..... </div>
</ngx-flyout>

<button (click)="toggleTopbar('X')">
    Toggle Flyout
</button>
```

I want to make it so that when I click the Toggle Flyout button, it opens up the flyout from the top and given that it is a short height (200px) that it scrolls to the specific div that is where the letter is. For example, if it was toggleTopbar('X'), it should scroll to where the div 'X' is instead of having the user manually scroll past divs A to W to get to it.

How do I accomplish this with my toggleTopbar function? I am using angular8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to calculate the UI sizes, which then can be used to scroll you div according to value provided.

I have calculated the values using `ViewChild` and whenever use clicks the button the function uses those value to calculate how much to scoll.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ylkwlu)

```html
<button (click)="toggleSidebar('Z')">
  Toggle Flyout Z
</button>

<ngx-flyout [(open)]="openFlyout">
    <div #innerList style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div id="A">Lorem ipsum...A</div>
        <div id="B">Lorem ipsum...B</div>
        <div id="C">Lorem ipsum...C</div>
        ...
        ...
        <div id="X">Lorem ipsum...X</div>
        <div id="Y">Lorem ipsum...Y</div>
        <div id="Z">Lorem ipsum...Z</div>
    </div>
</ngx-flyout>
```

```js
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  // get div from ngx-flyout
  @ViewChild("innerList", { static: false }) innerList: ElementRef;

  uiData = {
    innerDivHeight: 0,
    parentDivHeight: 0,
    noOfChildrenInParentDiv: 0,
    noOfChildrenInTotal: 0
  };

  openFlyout: boolean = false;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // get height of parent div
    this.uiData.parentDivHeight = this.innerList.nativeElement.clientHeight;
    // get height of div inside the parent div
    this.uiData.innerDivHeight = this.innerList.nativeElement.firstChild.clientHeight;
    // get number of elements visible in parent div
    this.uiData.noOfChildrenInParentDiv = Math.floor(
      this.uiData.parentDivHeight / this.uiData.innerDivHeight
    );
    // get total number of children present in parent div
    this.uiData.noOfChildrenInTotal = this.innerList.nativeElement.children.length;
  }

  toggleSidebar(id: string) {
    // get index of div (converted ASCII to number, you can use numbers here directly)
    // in case of numbers there is no need of following conversion
    let index = id.charCodeAt(0) - 65 + 1;
    this.openFlyout = !this.openFlyout;

    // if index is out of view of current visible children
    if (index > this.uiData.noOfChildrenInParentDiv) {
      const scrollPos = (this.uiData.innerDivHeight * (index - this.uiData.noOfChildrenInParentDiv));
      this.innerList.nativeElement.scrollTop = scrollPos;
    }
    // else reset scroll
    else {
      this.innerList.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ngx-flyout [(open)]="openFlyout">
 <div style="width:200px;height:200px;overflow:y;">
 <div id="idA">Lorem ipsum</div>
 <div id="idB">Lorem ipsum</div>
 <div id="idC">Lorem ipsum</div>
 <div id="idD">Lorem ipsum</div>
 <div id="idE">Lorem ipsum</div>
 </ngx-flyout>
```

`<a href="#idD">Toggle Flyout</a>`

Switching the button element with  and using css to make the  look like a button if its needed.